# No Data Source Name to select; Check for and remove synonym to a database project

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, oracle11g, data-connections

My Visual studio, on opening a certain project, builds so fast but takes forever to start running. I [searched](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/056339c1-8846-47e0-a099-eaa82e1ff909/visual-studio-2010-freezes-in-one-particular-solution-after-checkin) and found it is saying something like: "Adding a synonym to the database project" is the root cause.

I tried to re-add the data connection from Server Explorer. However, there used to be a long dropdown list to select the Data Source Name, but now only (local Database).....

Could anyone help please....

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 oracles installed on my VM.... and the one I am using, it actually maps to a version which does not have C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin/tnsnames.ora and another file.

I got a new VM machine, and it's solved.